# Authorize users of web application and allow them to access the API service

Tags: .net, azure, security, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I would like to know the possible security mechanisms can be implemented for the below requirement.

I have one API Server which have multiple api services which will provide the data.
(For example Graph API)

I wanted to allow access to these data by few organisations. Organisations have their own websites so they will authenticate the users on behalf of them.

So all we need to do is authorise the user if he is requesting from the allowed organisations.

Is this can be implemented by OAuth?

Please suggest various security mechanisms from that can be implemented.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) **and what has been done so far to solve it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider to require JWT as authentication token. For API call, each user must request a signed JWT from his own organization, and include the JWT as authorization header. You set up your API server to only trust JWT signed from those organizations. Typically your validation logic will verify if token is signed by those organizations, and contain matching token issuer claim "iss", and also check expiration time. You could also require those organizations to list your api server as token audience (included in "aud" claim). If token is trusted and validated, you could further authorize the user based on other claims inside token.

Here in MicroProfile community, we try to define an interoperable way to address the similar scenarios you described, https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-jwt-auth/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/interoperability.asciidoc

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Microsoft OWIN ? You can implement your own Authorization provider inheriting from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider - bearer token with username/password auth etc
https://georgedyrra.com/2016/09/28/using-owin-to-self-host-web-api-and-secure-endpoints/

Comment: My question here is how should i validate the user in API server. Because web api server doesn't know about the users. They are actually vendor organisation users(Web Application). What kind of mechanism we follow here?. What do we pass from web application to API server to tell that this user is already authenticated and just allow them to access the data?